# The false element in a Logical operation

Tags: java, c#

I wish to know if there's some way to know which is the elemnet of a logic operation is false?
Example.

```
if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj1) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj2) )
   throw("...............");
```

How can I kown which one of those is the empty one?

Comment: To handle the condition results for each case separately, the better way is to write 2 nested if statements . any other way will either be more complex or add more variables or methods but no real value to the code quality or to the execution speed.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot know which one of the subexpressions is empty, unless you repeat the checks.

Alternatively, you can separate the above code into two separate `if` statements, duplicating the `throw("...")` part.

Answer (score 3):

You can't know that in your code. But you can simply create two variables, that contain the parts of the condition and then check which one of them is `true` (at least one of them will) and which `false` (at most one of them).

```
bool isObj1Empty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj1);
bool isObj2Empty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj2);
if (isObj1Empty || isObj2Empty)
   throw("...............");
```

Answer (score 1):

This almost belongs on CodeReview. Here is how I would deal with this fairly cleanly, without checking things twice:

```
public void DoSomething(string obj1, string obj2)
{
    CheckStrArgNotEmpty(name: "obj1", value: obj1);
    CheckStrArgNotEmpty(name: "obj2", value: obj2);

    // Optionally:
    obj1 = obj1.Trim(); // obj1, obj2 are bad names btw
    obj2 = obj2.Trim();

    // The rest of the code ...
}

private static CheckStrArgNotEmpty(string argName, string value)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(value)) // or IsNullOrEmpty ?
    {
        return;
    }

    string exceptionMessage = String.Format(
        "Argument named '{0}' is null or empty but it should not have been."
        argName);
    throw new ArgumentException(message: exceptionMessage);
}
```